# Charts.js renders axes, but not the dataset

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to use Charts.js on an AWS Lambda function to create a chart image (png).

However, for some reason it plots the axes, but no data.

this is my code:

```js
export const plotData = (values: number[]): Buffer | null => {
  const canvas = createCanvas(800, 600);
  let ctx: ChartItem = canvas as unknown as ChartItem;

  const plugin: Plugin = {
    id: "customCanvasBackgroundColor",
    beforeDraw: (chart: any, _args: any, options: any) => {
      const { ctx: context } = chart;
      context.save();
      context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
      context.fillStyle = options.color || "#99ffff";
      context.fillRect(0, 0, chart.width, chart.height);
      context.restore();
    },
  };

  const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "line",
    data: {
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "ph",
          data: values.map((y) => ({
            y,
            t: new Date(),
          })),
          borderWidth: 2,
          borderColor: "red",
          backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 0, 0, 0.5)",
        },
      ],
    },
    options: {
      responsive: false,
      animation: false,
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true,
        },
      },
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          position: "top",
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: "TEstuibg",
        },
        customCanvasBackgroundColor: {
          color: "rgba(255,255,255, 1)",
        },
      },
    },
    plugins: [plugin],
  });

  // chart.draw();
  chart.update();

  return canvas.toBuffer("image/png");
};
```

And this is what it is rendering when I call `plotData([100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 1600])`:

[image]

I am already disabling animations and responsiveness. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Just wanted to know If my answer helped, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I would create the image on the `onComplete` event, than everything should be visible, atleast this works in browsers.

> from the documentation: *"...The animation configuration provides callbacks which are useful for synchronizing an external draw to the chart animation...."*, but works surely for your image creating process. [link to documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/animations.html)

```
...
options: {
  animation:{
        duration: 0, // "no" animation 
        onComplete: () => { 
            ...
            // create image
            ... 
        }
    }
}
...
```

**Ofcourse:** in this case your function `plotData`  would have to be *async* or pass a *callback function* for when the event `onComplete` fires.